# tooltip not working with local images

Tags: jquery, html, tooltip

I want to make a tooltip containing an image for a button.

With this code it works fine:

```
$( document ).tooltip({
  items: "button",
  content: function() {
       var element = $( this );
       if (element.attr('id') === 'surah') {
           return "<img src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/91/Wien_Stefansdom_DSC02656.JPG/450px-Wien_Stefansdom_DSC02656.JPG' />";
       }
    }
});
```

but with this one, it does not (i checked many times picture path)

```
$( document ).tooltip({
  items: "button",
  content: function() {
       var element = $( this );
       if (element.attr('id') === 'surah') {
           return "<img src='../img/home.jpg' />";
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: so the local path is correct or not?

Comment: `../` is a relative path, are you sure that's where the images are, and remember that if your javascript is included from an external file, it's not relative to the .js file, but to the file where it's included etc.

Comment: yes i am sure about it :)

Comment: As a sidenote, `if (this.id == 'surah') return 'image.jpg';` would do!

Comment: @adeneo it is that, thanks. put it as answer: )

Comment: @abualbara  it is what? `(this.id == 'surah')` instead of `(element.attr('id') === 'surah')` ???

Comment: @roasted - I'm that good, I just solved it without posting anything useful, and the credit goes entirely to my invaluable crystal ball.

Comment: @adeneo  you are lucky, i want one :)

Comment: any on of you put the correct answer guys ;)

Comment: @abualbara - and whats the correct answer ?

Comment: it's your: '../ is a relative path, are you sure that's where the images are, and remember that if your javascript is included from an external file, it's not relative to the .js file, but to the file where it's included etc'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's your: '../ is a relative path, are you sure that's where the images are, and remember that if your javascript is included from an external file, it's not relative to the .js file, but to the file where it's included.

Try:

```
if (this.id == 'surah') return 'image.jpg';
```

**Linking paths correctly is very important!**